# send mail is not working

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, rhel

for ex :  i ahve aliases  :

testuser

```
sendmail -v testuser@localhost < t.mail , this is working
```

but when i am trying from another host

`sendmail -v testuser@host.company.com < t.mail` .. its not working .. i am not receiveing mail

what is the issue how to reslove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you accept mail for host.company.com?
Do you have a MX record for host.company.com pointing to your MTA?